# Connecting buttons

Tags: javascript, html

Ok so I am trying to make a code where by clicking one button you hide a button and make another appear. All the buttons appear and work but I have no clue how to make button 3 and 4 be hidden until button one is clicked.

```
    <input type="button" onclick="b()";>no</button>
    <script>
    function a() {
    alert ("button 1")
    }
    function b() {
    alert ("button 2")
    }
     </script>

    <input type="button" onclick="c()";>button 3</button>
    <input type="button" onclick="d()";>button 4</button>
    <script>
    function c() {
      alert ("button 3")
    }
    function d() {
      alert ("button 4")
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
function button1Clicked() {
  document.getElementById('3').classList.remove('hidden');
  document.getElementById('4').classList.remove('hidden');
}
```

```css
.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<input type="button" id="1" value="Button 1" onclick="button1Clicked();" />
<input type="button" id="2" value="Button 2" />
<input type="button" id="3" class="hidden" value="Button 3" />
<input type="button" id="4" class="hidden" value="Button 4" />
```

Normally, you would keep your HTML, JS, and CSS in separate files.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="my.css">
</head>
<body>
    <script type="text/javascript" href="my.js"></script>
    <input type="button" id="1" value="Button 1" onclick="button1Clicked();" />
    <input type="button" id="2" value="Button 2" />
    <input type="button" id="3" class="hidden" value="Button 3" />
    <input type="button" id="4" class="hidden" value="Button 4" />
</body>
</html>
```

If you want to keep everything in one file, you could just replace the `link` tag with a `style` tag and keep your JS in the `script` tag, like so:

```
<style>
    .hidden {
        display: none;
    }
</style>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function button1Clicked() {
        document.getElementById('3').classList.remove('hidden');
        document.getElementById('4').classList.remove('hidden');
    }
</script>
```

Comment: where does the .hidden {
  display: none;
}   go

Comment: @Dylane2020 Updated my answer to go more in detail about that.